# IBM RAD - Rational Application Developer - Error update LCD

Tags: ibm-rad, launch-configuration

I'm trying to edit an existing launch configure that I have imported, but as soon as I click on it I have the followinf error:

[Error when I click on the launch configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6rA8.png)

I have no idea what to do to fix it. Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve my problem I simply went to Preferences/Server/Runtime Environments, removed my current server and added it again.

It was probably a reference issue on RAD.